# Discard duplicated array object base on property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
myArr = [{"name":"abc"},{"name":"efg"},{"name":"abc"}]
```

How to eliminated array that have redundant property value?

Comment: you mean you have to remove the same prop right?

Comment: So you have not tried anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) then here is inbuild function `_.uniq`

```
var myArr = [{"name":"abc"},{"name":"efg"},{"name":"abc"}];
var newArr = _.uniq(myArr, 'name');
```

Output:

```
[{"name":"abc"},{"name":"efg"}]
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLhd1nrh/)